Typescript error when creating an array of objects with different keys using map
I am trying to create an array of objects dynamically. These objects may contain different keys, though they always follow the same format (defined on myType, e.g.). However, when doing so, Typescript gives an error. Here's a minimal example.
type myType = {
  [key: string]: number;
};

const doesNotComplain: myType[] = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }];

const doesComplain: myType[] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].map((e) => {
  if (e == 1) return { a: 1 };
  return { b: 2 };
});

Gives the following error on doesComplain only.
Type '({ a: number; b?: undefined; } | { b: number; a?: undefined; })[]' is not assignable to type 'myType[]'.
  Type '{ a: number; b?: undefined; } | { b: number; a?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'myType'.
    Type '{ a: number; b?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'myType'.
      Property 'b' is incompatible with index signature.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

What I tried:
Although not exactly the same issue, I've seen some similar problems, but it seemed to me that none of the solutions would work.
The solution shown here, e.g., needs the array to have a fixed amount of values, so it doesn't fit my case.
Some solutions similar to this one, e.g., suggest defining myType with number | undefined, thought I wouldn't like to do so, since I don't expect any of the keys to have undefined values. If the key exists on the object, its value will be defined.
The only way to remove the error until now was to add // @ts-ignore above doesComplain, but that kinda defeats the purpose of using Typescript.

The easiest safe solution here is not to rely on the type inferred by TypeScript for the value returned by the map callback, but instead to explicitly annotate the return type of the callback to be what you want it to be:
const x: MyType[] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].map(
  (e): MyType => e == 1 ? { a: 1 } : { b: 2 }
  // ^^^^^^^^ <-- annotate
);

In fact, once you do that, you don't even need to annotate the x variable. The type of x is inferred to be MyType[]:
const x = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].map(
  (e): MyType => e == 1 ? { a: 1 } : { b: 2 }
);

And an annotation is better than a type assertion because it's more type safe; the annotation will catch errors that type assertions won't:
const x = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].map(
  (e): MyType => e == 1 ? { c: "oops" } : { b: 2 } 
  // error! ---> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
);

const x = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].map(
  (e) => (e == 1 ? { c: "oops" } : { b: 2 }) as MyType
  // no error, type assertions allow type mismatches
);

That's how to fix it, but why does it happen?

Well, you've run into the issue reported at microsoft/TypeScript#59180.
TypeScript normalizes unions of object literal types so that the cross-term properties are known to be absent. This was implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#19513 and released with TypeScript 2.7:
const f = (e: number) => e == 1 ? { a: 1 } : { b: 2 };
/* const f: (e: number) => { a: number; b?: never; } | { b: number; a?: never; } */

In the above, TypeScript infers that f returns a value of a type with either a numeric a property and definitely no b property, or a numeric b property and definitely no a property.  These "known to be absent" properties are written as optional properties of the impossible never type.
But unless you explicitly turn on the --exactOptionalPropertyTypes compiler option, TypeScript adds undefined to optional property value types, and unfortunately the undefined does not play nicely with index signatures.
So then { a: number; b?: never; } | { b: number; a?: never; } is equivalent to  { a: number; b?: undefined; } | { b: number; a?: undefined; } and thus not assignable to MyType, and you get an error.

It's unlikely that TypeScript will change to address this directly. There are a lot of tricky issues around telling the difference between properties that are missing versus ones which are present-but-undefined, and a lot of confusing compiler options like --exactOptionalPropertyTypes and --noUncheckedIndexedAccess, and messing with the status quo tends to make things worse and not better.
So you'll need to work around it. The easiest approach is to annotate the expected return type explicitly, as shown above.
You can also avoid normalization by not returning object literals directly:
const r1 = { a: 1 };
const r2 = { b: 2 };
const f = (e: number) => e == 1 ? r1 : r2;
/* const f: (e: number) => { a: number; } | { b: number;  } */
const u: MyType[] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].map(f); // okay

Here instead of returning fresh object literals, we're returning existing objects whose types are {a: number} and {b: number}. These don't get normalized, so f returns {a: number} | {b: number}, and that type is assignable to MyType.  This is more verbose, but there are some use cases where it might be desirable (especially if you don't really need to synthesize a new object for each element of the array).
Playground link to code

when i see type assertion in the most cases that's an ugly hack and bad typescript, your answer is excellent as usual

I have faced a similar problem, and loss hair trying to understand what is going on.
First off, lets look at your .map() result without typing the variable.
const untypedMappedResult = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].map((e) => {
  return (e === 1) ? { a: 1 } : { b: 2 };
});

/*
const untypedMappedResult: ({
    a: number;
    b?: undefined;
} | {
    b: number;
    a?: undefined;
})[]
*/

As you can see, the result is not what you expect.  Both objects in the union have two properties.
To fix this, you should just provide a type assertion...
const typedMappedResult = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].map((e) => {
  return ((e === 1) ? { a: 1 } : { b: 2 }) as myType;
});

/*
const typedMappedResult: myType[]
*/

Notice that I did not need to type the variable; it is inferred.
Playground Example

type assertions are usually  bad hacked typescript

@AlexanderNenashev - very good point.  jcalz offers an excellent reason to avoid type assertions.  "And an annotation is better than a type assertion because it's more type safe; the annotation will catch errors that type assertions won't:"  Thanks for catching this!
